# RegEx and Parsing

Tags: regex

I want to replace `password=aaa` to `password=bbb`.

How can I do that using RegEx?

My string is:

`string input = "user=fred;password=aaa;server=localhost";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a language I'll just make my answer generic. What function/method you use will depend on the language.

Regular Expression: `(?<=password=).*?(?=;)`

Replacement: `newpassword`

And here's a working example: http://fiddle.re/jn2b

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify your language I assume you're scripting in Bash :)

```
$ echo $input | sed s/password=aaa/password=bbb/
user=fred;password=bbb;server=localhost
```

The exact syntax depends on what language you use.

Comment: I use C#. Can I C# example?